# Highlight button by pressing it

Tags: ios, swift

How can I highlight a button that I replaced with an image like a normal button with a textLabel by pressing it? When I press this button [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeV8g.jpg) the action is going to be activated but there is no feedback of the button itself.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PlayMusicViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var daten = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Kool_Savas_Auge", ofType: "mp3")

        var filePathUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(daten!)

        do{
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathUrl, fileTypeHint: nil)

                }
        catch let err as NSError{
            print(err.debugDescription);
        }

    }

    @IBAction func PlayMusic(sender: UIButton) {

        audioPlayer.play()

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: Hi there - are you asking how to add a target to a UIImageView as you would to a UIButton? Except that you don't want the image to "click" like a UIButton would? Also, are you talking about iOS or OSX?

Comment: Update your question with relevant code for what you have so far.

Comment: I insert the code

Comment: I'm asking how to make a image that has a function like a button respond the same way as an actual button with a label. For example when you press a button with a label it gets a bit grey and I want that effect to happen with the image.